# Star filter effect in Blender?

Tags: compositing-nodes

Is it possible to achieve a realistic 'star filter' effect procedurally in Blender? I think the glare node in the compositor might help me, but it doesn't seem to have the rainbow color effect that I'm looking for.

[image]

Comment: Possible isolate the highlights, then add glare and use a colorramp node with RGB in it to control the color of the glare?

Comment: Have a look at the [flares wizard addon](http://codeofart.com/flares-wizard/).